# Can Scala load SparkR-saved model?

Tags: scala, sparkr

I'm a data analyst. I want to train a model (for example randomforest) and this model can be saved and loaded by Scala. Since both Scala and R are using MLlib for machine learning, can Scala also load the model trained and saved in SparkR?

I found an article saying that it was not compatible:
https://databricks.com/blog/2016/05/31/apache-spark-2-0-preview-machine-learning-model-persistence.html

But it was written almost a year ago. Does the latest, even development version, of SparkR support this cross-compatibility of model?

Answer (score 0):

**Code**: To Save and Load Model in Spark

```
 val model = pipeline.fit(training)

 // Now we can optionally save the fitted pipeline to disk
 model.write.overwrite().save("/tmp/spark-logistic-regression-model")

 // We can also save this unfit pipeline to disk
 pipeline.write.overwrite().save("/tmp/unfit-lr-model")

 // And load it back in during production
 val sameModel = PipelineModel.load("/tmp/spark-logistic-regression-model")
```

For More details refer

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-pipeline.html#example-pipeline

**Hope this Helps!!!...**